# Align 2 tables in same line with phpWord

Tags: php, phpword

I'm looking for a solution to align multiple table in same line with phpWord.

Actually this code give me that result :

```
$section = $word->createSection();

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");

$section->addText("");

$table = $section->addTable();

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");
```

[image: Actual rending]

But I'm looking for a result like this : 
[image: Wanted rending]

Any one have a solution?
I didn't found any information, let me know if it's dupplicated question.

Regards,

Comment: easiest way is to wrap your tables in a table ;)

Comment: I know that solution but can't use it, looking for an other way to made it. The problem is when you will edit your word document, you can see the property of the parent table. I have to find a solution without a parent table. Or any other Object. Parent have to be the document. Like when you drag and drop the table on the word doc to align it with the first table

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is not possible in PHPWord. When you drag and drop the Tables in Word and the check out the Word-XML (just unpack the .docx file) you will see a `<w:tblPr>` tag with table style properties (in this case, something like Table Grid). I don't think PHPWord is able to handle that particular style.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating nested tables.

**Step 1:** Add a Parent Table with one row and two columns(cells)

```
//Create a section
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section_1 = $phpWord->addSection();

//Define your parent table styles
$parent_table_styles = array('valign' => 'center', 'cellMarginRight' => 200);
$phpWord->addTableStyle('parent_table_styles', $parent_table_styles);

//Add a parent table     
$parent_table = $section_1->addTable('parent_table_styles');

//Add a row to the parent table
$parent_table_row_1 = $parent_table->addRow();

//Add a cell to that parent table row
$parent_table_row_1_cell_1 = $parent_table_row_1->addCell();

//Add another cell to that parent table row
$parent_table_row_1_cell_2 = $parent_table_row_1->addCell();
```

**Step 2:** Add Child Tables(Nested Tables) inside Parent Table Cells

```
//Define your child table and child table cell styles
$child_table_styles = array('valign' => 'center', 'borderSize' => 6, 'borderColor' => '999999');
$phpWord->addTableStyle('child_table_styles', $child_table_styles);
$child_table_cell_styles = array('valign' => 'center');
$phpWord->addTableStyle('child_table_cell_styles', $child_table_cell_styles);

//Add your first child table inside 'cell_1' of the parent table row
$child_table_1 = $parent_table_row_1_cell_1->addTable('style_child_table');
$child_table_1->addRow(200);
$child_table_1->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 1");
$child_table_1->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 2");
$child_table_1->addRow(200);
$child_table_1->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 1");
$child_table_1->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 2");

//Add your second child table inside 'cell_2' of the parent table row
$child_table_2 = $parent_table_row_1_cell_2->addTable('style_child_table');
$child_table_2->addRow(200);
$child_table_2->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 1");
$child_table_2->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 2");
$child_table_2->addRow(200);
$child_table_2->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 1");
$child_table_2->addCell(1200, $child_table_cell_styles)->addText("Col 2");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm trying to find a solution without a parent object (direct parent of each table have to be a section).

Comment: @Paulo Why is it necessary to have the document as the direct parent of those two tables?

Comment: Customer needs, to be able to edit the doc. But we change the data structure so no anymore a problem now, but still looking for a solution, I guess I gonna try to implement an extention in phpWord for the flag "<w:tblPr>". But a bit busy till end of month. If I do smth "fun" & "nice", will keep this post updated